# Pivot SQL Table or other solution - Find Max Column

Tags: sql, amazon-ec2, pivot, ssms

```
ARType  F10 F12 F13 F14
PVT     3   3   6   3
MCD     114 114 228 114
MP      10  10  20  10
MRA     8   8   16  8
HOS     2   2   4   2
MMA     2   2   4   2
```

I need to Pivot this data so that I can get the Max column only. Its not always the same column so I will need find it

I need:

```
ARType Max
PVT    6
MCD    228
```

Edit: There could be more or less columns. (F1-F30). Some columns could be NULL and I would need to find the Max of the non-null values. And Greatest isnt a built in function for my DB

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: NULL means unknown, therefore you could add to the question if any of the values is NULL then the result should also be NULL or the MAX of the non-NULL values

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support `greatest()`:

```
select ARType, greatest(F10, F12, F13, F14) as max_f
from t;
```

If your database doesn't you can always use a `case` expression.